# How to write own ISR handler

Tags: arduino, avr, interrupts, programming

I am learning about AVR programming and I know we have to use avr/interrupt.h library to use interrupts. However, my main reason to learn AVR programming is to program without any library so I want to know how can I handle interrupts without using any libraries such as avr/interrupt.h?

Comment: interrupt.h is not a "library", it is a header file. If you don't want to use it (and I can't imagine why you won't) then read through it carefully to understand what it does and why. Then reinvent the wheel and write your own code to do the same thing.

Comment: Even if you avoid using header files you are still going to be using libraries under the covers. Your program will be compiled and then linked with some kind of runtime library(s) to generate a binary (or make calls to a dynamically linked library). The only true way to potentially avoid the use of libraries is to write your program standalone in machine code/assembler. This would be a heroic effort and you'd probably learn a lot trying to do this exercise but in the real world we use headers and libraries to make writing code manageable and maintainable.

Comment: you certainly do not need to use any existing header file to create an interrupt handler.  nor do you need to use a specific programming language that uses headers like that, read the docs, start simple with assembly language then if you want to complicate your life try C or other.   Understanding that in all cases the syntax of the language is specific to the tool for this kind of thing, specific C compiler or environment not any C compiler.  assembly language is specific to the assembler not the target (avr).   just read the docs, start simple.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because not about electronics

Comment: @DavideAndrea - Hi, You said you were voting to close the question "*because not about electronics*". However the list of "our" on-topic subjects [is not limited to electronics](/help/on-topic) and the topic of writing firmware is specifically mentioned there. We have some overlap with [so] whose on-topic list looks like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). In some cases, e.g. more generic firmware programming questions, I would be more likely to ask on SO, but that does *not* make them off-topic here. If you have questions about our on-topic list, please ask on our [meta]. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You use the ISR() macros in like function declarations.
Here's an example:

```
#include <avr/interrupt.h>

ISR(TIMER1_OVF_vect)
{
   if (u8_some_flag) {
      u8_some_variable = SOME_VALUE;
      SOME_SPECIAL_FUNCTION_REGISTER |= (1<<SOME_BIT);
   }
}
```

In principle those 300+ page datasheets have everything you need, including showing how to enable the various interrupts etc. It can take some time.

Interrupt programming takes a bit of extra care. As a general rule you want to keep the code inside the interrupts as short as possible, and be aware of accessing multi-byte values outside the interrupt, since the interrupt can happen anytime, including when a multi byte value is in the middle of being transferred from memory to a register in the main code.

Comment: But i don't want to use interrupt.h because i want to learn what is really happening inside the ISR function and i want to write my isr by my own without including any header file

Comment: ISR() is a macro. Go take a look at interrupt.h to see how it's implemented. It basically expands to something like "void intN_handler()", possibly with some attributes so that the linker can point a jump instruction at it from the interrupt vector table.

Comment: @Syed  you can but why? If you want to know how an ISR works, read the datasheet. It just copies a function pointer into a jump table (one ptr for each interrupt). The table has a fixed pre-determined location in memory, usually right at the beginning. The attributes mentioned by alex tell the compiler to use a different preamble at the beginning of the isr function, and finish by calling IRET instead of RET when you "return" in C. That's all there is. If you want to "go deep" into what you can get out of this chip, there are better things to do than redefine headers.

Comment: If you want to know what is happening then do not use C, make life easier and use assembly language for the ISR itself.  The setup, use whatever is easiest for you.

Answer (score 1):

The interrupt.h is not a library but a standard avr-gcc header file which provides a standard way of defining interrupt handlers to make the compiler know the function you are defining is an interrupt.

What you are suggesting to work without the header, while possible, makes little sense. It is similar to not wanting to use PORTB name for writing an IO port, but using the address of the IO port instead of the name, or not including any other standard library if it contains the functions you need.

Comment: Yes i want to use isr without any header file please can you help me how to attach my isr code to interrupt in programming without including any header file

Comment: Then you should copy whatever you need from the header file. I don't think you'll be satisfied with understanding how it really works by trying to do without the header file, because the header file and using the macros there only instruct the compiler to do things and finally the linker puts all pieces into place. Maybe you'd like to write the program in assembly, where you do are in total control, or take a look at C compiler output assembly listing to see that it's not all that magical after all.

Answer (score 0):

The generic steps generally involve:

-setting the appropriate bits in registers to enable the interrupt

-write the function for the ISR handler using a function name that has been specifically pre-designated to be associated with that interrupt